# How do I figure out which routes a mobile app is using in my Laravel application?

Tags: laravel

Here's the situation:

- I have a Laravel application
- there is a mobile application, to which I do not have the source code (the client had a falling out with the previous developers)
- we need to build a new mobile app which does essentially the same things as the previous one
- I would like to use the same routes the previous mobile app used

The thing is, I don't know which routes the old app is using.

In the `routes` directory we have:

```
api.php
channels.php
console.php
legacy_app.php
web.php
```

I am trying to send requests to these routes with Postman, but they always return an empty response.

I know I can go through the back-end code, try logging stuff while using the app, etc, but I would much prefer a way to reliably get a list of routes and required parameters. Is there any way at all to accomplish this?

Comment: If done correctly, the `api.php` should contain the API routes that the mobile app uses.

Comment: you can use in command line : "php artisan route:list" for have got list of route in your application

Comment: Take a look at Laravel Telescope and install it in your project, it will log all the incoming requests